# XNA model import - All meshs appear on top of each other

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, 3dsmax

I have created a scene in 3DS Max with a stock engine model and some things i added my self, the plane, and the button.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2iva.png

Regardless of how i export the scene, whether its as a .X using panda exporter or .fbx using 2012.2 fbx exporter both, when loaded into XNA and rendered, all appear on top of each other.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gdMb.png

Since the individual parts of the engine all remain where they should (and are seperate in 3ds max) im pretty sure there is something im not setting correctly in 3ds max with the layout of the rest of my objects.

Update 1 : The code i use to load the models in xna is as follows

```
        Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
        model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect be in mesh.Effects)
            {
                be.EnableDefaultLighting();
                be.Projection = camera.projection;
                be.View = camera.view;
                be.World = GetWorld() * mesh.ParentBone.Transform;
                // adding the additional * transforms[i]; didnt do anything  

            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
```

This code works great for other peoples models but not any that i make. Its like 3ds max isnt exporting out the positions of the objects that i create in the scene relative to the scenes origin.

Comment: Just so that you know, the panda X exporter sometimes doesn't work right with XNA.

Comment: Have you tried downloading a model from the internet and using it to test whether it's your code or the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine all the transform matrices from parent bones and child bones like this:

```
Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes) {
    foreach (BasicEffect ef in mesh.Effects) {
        ef.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index];
        //Also do other stuff here, set projection and view matrices
    }
}
```

There is probably a better way, but this code should work.

Comment: I don't think that you need the additional `* transforms[i]`

Comment: @Neil If you can confirm that, I'll remove it

Comment: Updated my answer with the code i use to show how im loading in the models

Comment: @annonymously Neil is correct. No need for the additional '* transforms[i]', the transforms[m.pb.i] is enough. But that is a good place for a world transform that you would want to apply to all the meshes of the model.